# Как скачать csv-файл с удаленного сервера через ftp используя gulp?

Tags: node.js, ftp, gulp

Пытаюсь скачать csv файл с удаленного сервера по ftp и сохранить его локально, используя gulp. Пробовал различные npm модули, но они либо не работают с ftp (gulp-download и gulp-download-stream), либо работают только на загрузку, а не на скачивание(vinyl-ftp). Кто-нибудь знает, как это сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Есть такие пакеты для node.js, как ftp-get и node-ftp, gulp'у тут вообще не место он сборщик проектов для фронтенда.